# Kafka Consumer not consuming messages after application restart

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Java application that consumer messages from a Kafka topic. Using following kafka client dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Once restarted, application stops consuming messages from the topic, just returns empty after poll timeout is expired. If the change the consumer group and restart the application, messages are picked until next restart. I have 10 partitions in the topic and if the describe the consumer group a lag is shown for the partition where data is available. If i recreate the topic with single partition, everything works fine. After seeing
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8950 i have upgraded the kafka-client to latest but still facing the issue.

Using following configuration, everything else is default

```
group.id: group-1
fetch.min.bytes: 1
fetch.max.wait.ms: 60000
max.poll.records: 1
max.poll.interval.ms: 120000
auto.offset.reset: earliest
enable.auto.commit: false
```

Seeing this in logs

> Setting offset for partition rawData-tp-3 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=6, offsetEpoch=Optional[0], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[wn3.b3fteyj4w3xuzpvo3wsrfzzila.ax.internal:9092 (id: 1002 rack: /rack0)], epoch=0}}

Anyone come across similar issue ?

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve]

Comment: Also, `max.poll.interval: 1` is not recommended. Kafka consumers default to poll up to 500 records at a time, to reduce network load on the brokers

Answer (score 0):

Could be caused by messages going to only one partition due to a static key being used or maybe issues with consumer shutdown leaving the previous consumer hanging and hitting a timeout, this might make the new consumer wait for that timeout to expire.